# Deploying Rails on Heroku after removing Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, devise, rubygems

I'm trying to deploy my first rails app on Heroku. I was using devise for authentication, but my needs changed, so I removed it and am now using sorcery.

Everything is working locally, but when deploying I get the following message when migrating my DB:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5220
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Devise
/app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:295:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I can't seem to find any remaining mentions of Devise. Has anybody else run into a problem like this after removing the gem?

Thanks!

Comment: You could search your whole codebase for `Devise` in a case-sensitive way with your editor to find any accidental remainders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to remove the Devise initializer file `/app/config/initializers/devise.rb`.

Comment: That file is not there: http://screencast.com/t/h6wsHgnUHS50 Is it possible that there's some kind of issue with git holding an old copy of it in the background or something?

Comment: @Nathan, try running `heroku run ls /app/config/initializers`?

Comment: ah yes. it's listed in there. Can i delete is as I normally would through terminal?

Comment: No, Heroku will recreate it as it seems to be present in your git repository. Run `git rm --cached config/initializers/devise.rb` (and commit and push), as you probably just removed it from the file system directly, not using `git rm`.